# Android set Exact Repeating Alarms WorkAround

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I am trying to set repeating alarms in an exact fashion by manually setting an alarm to the next day the moment I receive it in a broadcast. However, I might be missing something and somehow its not working. 
**The Logic:**

1. When I select the time from a time chooser, I set an exact alarm to the time given and start a pending intent which calls MyBroadCastReceiver.java (extends BroadcastReceiver) when its time. I then forward the intent with another pending intent to AlarmFireActivity. (AlarmFireActivity also has snooze which simply sets a pendingIntent to itself to fire after 5 mins.)
2. The MyBroadCastReceiver component hence only receives the actual alarms (not snoozes). And its functions are :
   a) Get the non-repeating pending intent cancel it, then create another pending intent from the intent and then set it with the milliseconds set to the next day at the same time.
   b) Start the AlarmFireActivity and show the alarm.

**In AddAlarmActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID,alarm.getId());
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (alarmManager != null) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, reminder.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, reminder.getHourOfDay());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, reminder.getMinuteOfHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
        BLog("Pending intent added at " + new SimpleDateFormat(utilFunctions.timeFormat).format(calendar.getTime()));
    }
```

**Snippet MyBroadCastReceiver.java**  ***TaskOne***

**Logic**

Get the intent which MyBroadCastReceiver receives. Reuse the same intent in a new PendingIntent set to the next day at the same time.

**Code**

```
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            PendingIntent p1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmCurrent.getReminderId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            if(p1!=null){
                alarmManager.cancel(p1);
            }
            PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmCurrent.getReminderId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            //for test
            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE,1);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pendingIntent1);

        }
```

**MyBroadCastReceiver.java *TaskTwo***

**Logic**

If the time when the alarm was set was after the time the alarm is due, do not forward the pending intent to the AlarmFireActivity. 
Else forward it to the AlarmFireActivity which shows the screen to dismiss/snooze the alarm.

**Code**

```
 Calendar timeSet = alarmCurrent.getAlarmReminderSetTime();
 Calendar alarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        if(timeSet!=null && alarmTime.getTimeInMillis() > timeSet.getTimeInMillis()){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmFireActivity.class);
            intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent1.putExtra(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID,id);
            String ext = extras.getString(DBHelper.TASK_TITLE);
            if(ext!=null){
                intent1.putExtra(DBHelper.TASK_TITLE,ext);
            }
            context.startActivity(intent1);
        }else{

        }
```

The BroadCastReceiver is doing the second task just fine. However, not the task one. Its not repeating/ resetting a new pending intent. I am guessing I must have messed up the intent/pendingIntent somewhere. I dont know which. Please help/

Comment: Why don't you use alarmManager.setRepeating(...) instead of setting a single alarm every time?

Comment: Yeah. But as can be seen here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html .SetRepeating is by default inExact which means it does not fire at Second 0 of a minute. But somewhere around 40. Not ideal.

Comment: Please paste here how do you create the intent in your broadcast receiver. Please also log out (BLog) with SimpleDateFormat the time of the calendar. Please note that you don't have to cancel an alarm if after it you use it again with set. It will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is **restart the phone**. I have seen somewhere that there is a bug in a one of the os' 4.3 or so. A pending intent with a request id of 0 might fail at times. And once I restarted the phone it worked. However, there is a more standard solution which is :

Replacing

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, reminder.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

with

```
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, A_NUMBER_GREATER_THAN_ZERO + reminder.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

so that you are avoiding a pending intent with 0 at all times. Thanks all!